# Scroll function of jQuery causing severe performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

```
 if($window.innerWidth > 1600) {

 $(window).scroll(function() {       
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollHandler);                                     
 });
}

var fixedElement = $('.fixedElement');
var divide = $('.divide');
var ghost = $(".ghost");
 var isPositionFixed = (fixedElement.css('position') == 'fixed');
var sponsor = $('.sponsor');
var ghost1 = $('.ghost1');

function scrollHandler() {

                  if ($(this).scrollTop() >=64  && !isPositionFixed){

                      fixedElement.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'z-index': '200' });   
                      divide.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0' });
                      ghost.removeClass("hidden");

                  } else if($(this).scrollTop()< 64)
                  {

                    fixedElement.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0'});
                      divide.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0' });
                      ghost.addClass("hidden");

                  } 

                   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 850 )
                         {
                        $('.sponsor').css({'position': 'fixed', 'z-index': '100', 'top': '-200', 'width': '22.8%', 'float': 'right'}); 
                      ghost1.removeClass("hidden1");


                  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 850)  {

                        $('.sponsor').css({'position': 'static', 'z-index': '0', 'top': '0'}); 
                         ghost1.addClass("hidden1");                         
                  }
}
```

this is my javascript code in the angular controller. I am trying to fix the half of the header after the window scrolled by 64 pixels and getting the whole header back if the window gets scrolled less than 64, similarly I am doing this  for the right side of the web page container after the header scrolls by 850 and getting it below 850.

But this is causing me very huge amount of scrolling issue. I am not able to scroll properly I know the causes behind it but I am not able to improve the performance.

Somebody please help. Is there any alternative way  ?

Comment: And does the issue go away when you stop using requestAnimationFrame and just call your method?

Comment: Start by replacing all superfluous function calls with vars. `var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st >= 64)` Further down, you use `$(".sponsor")` but you already have a var called `sponsor`.

Comment: @epascarello no, it's not going away even if I am simply calling the method inside.this is the link of the website I am building. Please look into that http://fathomless-anchorage-12312.herokuapp.com/#!/

Comment: @ChrisG okay, I will implement it and then let you know, how it's working. For the variable sponsor actually it was not working that'swhy I replaced it.
http://fathomless-anchorage-12312.herokuapp.com/#!/
please look into this link.

Comment: You need to make sure that `$(".sponsor")` is called *after* the DOM has fully loaded. Either put the assignment into `$(document).ready()` or move the script right before `</body>`.

Comment: @ChrisG I did that and it's working but the performance is still slow :( I think this is due to the scroll function being called at at each pixel of scrolling. I am still unable to find the alternative.